# R: Caculating new variable by category with a different equation for each category

Tags: r

I have been searching an answer to this for a while but nothing seems to fit me.

I have a dataframe called "data" that looks like this:

| Species | Length | Weight |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 15 | 0 |
| A | 8 | 0 |
| B | 20 | 0 |
| C | 4 | 0 |
| B | 11 | 0 |
| B | 16 | 0 |
| C | 13 | 0 |

What I would like to do is to calculate the weight of each individual of a species based on their length ant fill the Weigth column with the results. For that purpose, I have already obtained an equation for each species, since each species has a different length-weight relation. Lets say those length-weight equations look as follows:

- "A" species: weight=length*2
- "B" species: weight=length^3
- "C" species: weight=length/5

So, as a result, I would like to have have a dataframe that looks like this:

| Species | Length | Weight |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 15 | 30 |
| A | 8 | 16 |
| B | 20 | 8000 |
| C | 4 | 0.8 |
| B | 11 | 1331 |
| B | 16 | 4096 |
| C | 13 | 3.6 |

I have tried to do it this way:

```
Species <- c("A", "A", "B", "C", "B","B","C")
Length <- c(15,8,20,4,11,16,13)
Weight <- c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0)
data <- data.frame(Species, Length, Weight)

for(i in 1:length(data$Length)){if(data$Species[i]=="A"){
data$Weight[i]<-data$Length[i]*2
}else if(data$Species[i]=="B"){
data$Weight[i]<-data$Length[i]^3
}else if(data$Species=="C"){
data$Weight[i]<-data$Length[i]/5
} else {data$Weight[i]<-"NA"}
}
```

The code runs without error, but the data$Weigth column is not filled with the results. However, when I tried the code without using for() and replacing [i] with a row number (for example [4]), it did the correct thing and fills the Weight column with the result for that row.

In reality I have 40 species and over 5000 observations, so running the code for each row individually is not an option.

Any suggestions? Maybe there is an easier way but I don´t see it? Any help will be much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Try using `case_when`

Comment: The `\(x)` is the short form of `function(x)` in base R.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In base R you could do:

```
transform(df, 
  Weight = Vectorize(\(x, type) switch(type, A = x*2, B= x^3, C =x/5))(Length, Species))

  Species Length Weight
1       A     15   30.0
2       A      8   16.0
3       B     20 8000.0
4       C      4    0.8
5       B     11 1331.0
6       B     16 4096.0
7       C     13    2.6

library(tidyverse)
df %>%
  mutate(Weight = case_when(Species == 'A' ~Length * 2,
                            Species == 'B' ~ Length ^ 3,
                            Species == 'C' ~ Length / 5))
```

Comment: When using the  base R solution what does the \ inside Vectorize() mean/do? I've never seen it before and can't find info. about it